# Slider - preloader - buttons aren't working after setting style="display: none"

Tags: html, jquery, css, frontend

Could anyone have a look at this snippet of code?

I recreated another loader and included the last amount possible of code I could to show you the problem.
Basically I have a div container, which is `"all-page-container"` which has an inline `style="display: none"` which makes it  non visible until the loader is done (but also it makes it wait at least 2 seconds to show the actual page content).

But this also makes the js part of the code as

```js
var s = $('.slider'),
        sWrapper = s.find('.slider-wrapper'),
        sItem = s.find('.slide'),
        btn = s.find('.slider-link'),
        sWidth = sItem.width(),
        sCount = sItem.length,
        slide_date = s.find('.slide-date'),
        slide_title = s.find('.slide-title'),
        slide_text = s.find('.slide-text'),
        slide_more = s.find('.slide-more'),
        slide_image = s.find('.slide-image img'),
        sTotalWidth = sCount * sWidth;
```

Not find the actual classes, because of the display:none, does anyone know how could I overcome this issue?
I fixed it with a while loop which checks until a property is set to 0 to load the script, but obviously this isn't going to fix the major problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/boxxo/95ocxrb2/59/

if you remove the inline style="display:none", obviously the buttons are going to work ask expected and also the slider is going to work properly.

(The buttons are actually running, I added logs into the conditions and the "next" and "previous" are definitely executing correctly).

If anyone could help I would be grateful.
Thanks everyone.

(I also checked other questions on the site, but couldn't find the solution to my issue, and also other guys are using display: none to hide the page content until the preloader is done loading).

Comment: Can you explain what is exactly the issue? Because I don't actually understand the code in fiddle is working. And please upload the title with your actual question and the problem you have.

Comment: @jcubic Yes: as you can see here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/boxxo/95ocxrb2/63/) the buttons actually do work and I'm able to switch between images, meanwhile by setting an inline `style="display: none"` it doesn't, the buttons actually register the event but the images don't actually get pushed forward.

I'm going to edit the title.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Adding answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `width` of the element that is not visible (`display: none`) is 0 same as `height`. If initially, the page is not visible (width `display: none`) your animation will not work.

Just add `console.log({sWidth});` to see for yourself.

To solve the issue you can show the div before you start your code. Or use different CSS properties:

```css
visibility: hidden;
visibility: visible;
```

This property works similarly to `display: none` but the width and height is not 0, the element still occupies the same space but it's not visible.

Comment: The problem is that actually I can't use `visibility: hidden` , I had already tried that (should've included it in the question,my bad), because I'm working with components and I do already have the preloader+body+footer in the index, and the body+footer occupying space isn't nice to have, that's why I went with `display: none`: to not have space after the preloader(which is little in the jfiddle example, but in the real code It takes up 100vw-100vh).
Also I've tried working with z-index to have them on multiple layers but still it wasn't a good take, and I kinda fixed it with events raising.

Comment: @FrancescoBosso this is the answer to your question if you use `display: none` the width is 0. There is no other way to solve this you either show the component before you get the width or use visibility hidden. You can also think about a different way to animate the card. Sorry but I don't have time to rewrite your code and fix it for you. This is the answer to your question.

Comment: Don't worry about it, thanks anyway.

I'll have the js to load on a custom event that gets fired when the preloader ends.